# Check if current date falls in holiday date range

Tags: php, mysql

How to check if current date falls in holiday date range?
I have a table "holidays" with two DATE columns, start_date and end_date. Users can define holidays dates in that range. I need to make a loop that checks is the current date within the holiday date range, and if it is, the current date goes "+1 day", and checks again. I've made it so far:

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$curdate = date('Y-m-d', time());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE '$curdate' BETWEEN `start_date` and `end_date`");
$resu = mysql_num_rows($res);
 if ($resu == NULL)
      {
      echo "Date is not range";
      }
 else
    {
    echo "Date is in range";
    }
?>
```

Comment: And you'd like help from us to do what exactly?

Comment: I need help with creating a loop that makes the $curdate value next day if it falls in the predefined that range. Example:
start date = 2012-08-29
end date = 2012-08-31
current date = 2012-08-30
date is in range - current date = 2012-08-31
check again...
until current date = 2012-09-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a loop, so you can do it like this

```
<?php
   include ("config.php");
   $curdate = date('Y-m-d', time());
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM holidays WHERE '$curdate' BETWEEN `start_date` and `end_date`");
   $resu = mysql_num_rows($res);
   if ($resu == 0)
   {
      echo "Date is not range";
   }
   else
   {
      $res = mysql_query("SELECT end_date FROM holidays WHERE end_date > '$curdate' ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 1");
      $resu = mysql_fetch_array($res);

      $next_day = strtotime($resu['end_date']) + 24 * 60 * 60;
      echo 'The next available day is ' . date("Y-m-d", $next_day);
   }
?>
```

Comment: It says Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_test\test-vreme.php on line 5
Date is not range, although the date is in range, the range is set to be from August 29 to August 30

Comment: Probably you don't have an field named `id` so you have to put there an existing field. Check your query syntax

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks alot =)
And it will work with multiple holidays predefined, right?

Comment: Yes.. I've did that query to work with multiple holidays date ranges

Comment: Dude, help, in Windows on XAMPP the script works ok, it gives correct date, but on Debian, 'The next available day is 1970-01-02'. Debian system time is ok, NOW() in mySQL returns correct date, I can't figure out what is it.

Comment: I think that's because the returning value from mysql is `NULL`. There is nothing returned. Try to verify if there is an `end_date` bigger then your `$curdate`. If you changed your database there might be other stored data in it which is not applicable for the example above

Comment: So, I could try with mysql_affected_rows?

Comment: Just can't figure out what's wrong, same script on same database with same data on Windows works ok, and in Debian, returns year 1970.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16037/discussion-between-user1481792-and-matei-mihai)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<?php
  include ("config.php");
  $curdate = date('Y-m-d', time());

  while(1) {
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE '$curdate' BETWEEN `start_date` and `end_date`");
     if(!mysql_num_rows($res))
     {
         echo "Date is not range";
         break;
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Date is in range";
         $TS = strtotime($curdate);
         $curdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $TS));
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: When I echo $curdate after the last line, the output is
Date is in range2012-08-31Date is in range2012-09-01Date is not range
So, that's it, I just need to format it a little =)

Comment: Thanks alot dude, I voted you up, you and Matei gave me right answers, but I can select only one...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
include ("config.php");

$curdate = date('Y-m-d', time());

while(1)
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE '$curdate' BETWEEN `start_date` and `end_date` LIMIT 1");

    if( !mysql_num_rows($res) )
    {
        echo 'closest data available: ' . $curdate;
        break;
    }

    $ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $curdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", $ar['end_date']));
}
```

Comment: It outputs 1346450400, which is August 31, and my dates in holiday table are start date ('2012-08-29') and end date ('2012-08-31').
The output should be September 1st. Thanks, I think that we're almost there =)

Answer (score 0):

`$resu` will contain the number of resulted rows. So you have to verify if `$resu == 0`

Comment: Or I can put mysql_affected_rows, doesn't matter.